# How to pass additional postdata into an add record function - JQGrid - MVC . NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I am using the JQGrid plugin on an MVC project. I am trying to avoid using 'Session'. I have been able to pass extra postdata into my edit and delete functions, using the serializedata methods from JQGrid.

E.G.

```
serializeEditData: function (postdata) 
{
    var rowdata = jQuery('#gridId').getRowData(postdata.id);
    return {id: postdata.id, oper: postdata.oper, SomeExtraData: $('#extradata').val()};
}
```

However, there doesn't appear to be a serializeAddData function. Is there another way to alter the post data for the add method before it is sent?

Comment: Is there a reason you declare `var rowdata` and then return the function without ever using the variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are **one method** [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) which implement form editing for **both** "Edit" and "Add" dialogs. So the same event han`ler [serializeEditData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) can be used in both cases. For example,

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {/*navGrid options*/},
    {/*edit options*/
        serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
            // your implementation of serializeEditData for edit
        }
    },
    {/*add options*/
        serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
            // your implementation of serializeEditData for add
        }
    },
    {/*del options*/},
    {/*search options*/}
```

/   );

Typically `serializeEditData` event is very practical if you need convert **all** the posted data in another format, for example to make JSON serialization. To be able to pass extra postdata parameters you can use `editData` parameter instead which has the same meaning like `postData` parameter of jqGrid:

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {/*navGrid options*/},
    {/*edit options*/
     editData: {SomeExtraData: $('#extradata').val()}
    },
    {/*add options*/
     editData: {SomeExtraData: $('#extradata').val()}
    },
    {/*del options*/},
    {/*search options*/}
);
```

or better in this way (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) about the usage of functions as the property of `postData`):

```
$("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
    {/*navGrid options*/},
    {/*edit options*/
     editData: {SomeExtraData: function() {return $('#extradata').val();}}
    },
    {/*add options*/
     editData: {SomeExtraData: function() {return $('#extradata').val();}}
    },
    {/*del options*/},
    {/*search options*/}
);
```

Comment: @Rajpurohit: You are welcome! By the way one more good way is the usage of `onclickSubmit` callback. It can return object which *extend* the data in the same way like `editData`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16135162/315935). The main advantage of the way are additional options: `options, postData, oper`