# jqgrid: editData not being sent to server

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using guriddo jqGrid 5.2.1

I've followed the answers provided to these questions:

- [jqGrid: sending edit data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364343/jqgrid-sending-edit-data)
- [Add additional param to post data using jqGrid when adding new row with modal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184399/add-additional-param-to-post-data-using-jqgrid-when-adding-new-row-with-modal-fo)
- [How to post variable data with editData or onclickSubmit in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134827/how-to-post-variable-data-with-editdata-or-onclicksubmit-in-jqgrid)

But the editData I've defined is not getting sent to the endpoint.

Here is the code in my jqgrid pager definition:

```
$('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager',
            // the buttons to appear on the toolbar of the grid
            { edit: true, 
                add: true, 
                del: true, 
                search: false, 
                refresh: false, 
                view: false, 
                position: "left", 
                cloneToTop: false,
                mtype: 'POST',
                editData: {
                    mediaPlanId : function() { return mpId; }
                }},
            // options for the Edit Dialog
            {
                editCaption: "Edit Item",
                recreateForm: true,
                checkOnUpdate : true,
                checkOnSubmit : true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                    return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
                }
            },
            // options for the Add Dialog
            {
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                recreateForm: true,
                errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                    return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
                }
            },
            // options for the Delete Dailog
            {
                errorTextFormat: function (data) {
                    return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
                }
            }

    );
```

mpId is defined outside of the jqGrid and jqGridPager functions, at the page level.  I tried sending a value of 1, but that doesn't work either.  I suspect I've missed something simple, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  I updated the question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You place the `editData` parameter on the wrong place. The options of `navGrid` are very bad and one can made easy errors. I described the problem in detailed in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, which I develop.

Currently you placed `editData` in the options of `navGrid` instead of placing it in the options of Edit/Add, which are the options of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow). The problem is solved in free jqGrid, but if you do prefer to use commercial version of [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) then I would recommend you to rewrite your code in the following way:

```
var myErrorFunc = function (data) {
        return 'Error: ' + data.responseText;
    },
    addEditFormOptions = {
        editCaption: "Edit Item",
        recreateForm: true,
        checkOnUpdate : true,
        checkOnSubmit : true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        editData: {
            mediaPlanId : function() { return mpId; }
        },
        errorTextFormat: myErrorFunc
    },
    delOptions = {
        errorTextFormat: myErrorFunc
    };

$('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager', { search: false, refresh: false },
    addEditFormOptions, addEditFormOptions, delOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better approach is to read first the [documentation of Guriddo jqGrid](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/editing/#methods), which will guide you where to put the parameter.

Comment: I hadn't realized that there was an update to the documentation.  I kept referring to the old jqgrid wiki.  Thanks for letting me know!