# How to send few Params in jqgrid from edit form

Tags: jqgrid

I am new to jqgrid,  in my edit form contains few non editable fields and few editable fields. If I want send to only selective fields to server to update how to do that. ??

How to send all the params as object because in server method it’s difficult to write all the params in list.if I have 10 params it’s difficult to write..

Updatedata(string param1, string param2,string param3....string param10)
{
}

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for help with. Do you know how to create an object? You are definitely on the right track. Show us what you've tried and you're more likely to get a prompt answer. Click on edit and add your formatted code to the question.

Comment: Look at this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246555/how-to-pass-additional-postdata-into-an-add-record-function-jqgrid-mvc-net/5252503#5252503)